# Can't get access to string localizations in UI Test (Xcode 7)

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

So I have a situation in which I have a few textFields that are validated. I'm trying to run a UI test, and when they fail they will get an alert to pop up with an error message (potentially a different message depending on what fields are invalid and in what way).

I'd like to test that not only that an alert appeared, but that the correct message is displayed. The problem I'm having is that I need to get the localized text for comparison (if I run tests in another language other than english), but when I call NSLocalizedString in the UITest it can't gather the correct localized string (just returns the key [default])

I've tried adding the `localizeable.strings` files to the UITest target, but to no avail. Does anyone know if this is possible?

**edit as a side note:** I also tried setting an accessibility identifier on the `UIAlertView` but when I query with that accessibility identifier it doesn't exist, I can only query it using the title of the alert which seems backwards.

Comment: A workaround for this that I found is to force the app to launch in english, (launch argument) and then to test against the english string. Works but not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the UI tests, the main bundle seems to be a random launcher app. That's why the .strings file doesn't appear: even though you added it to your test bundle, NSLocalizedString is checking the wrong bundle. To get around this, you need an invocation like this:

```
NSLocalizedString("LOCALIZATION_KEY", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: AClassInYourUITests.self), comment: "")
```

Which you might want to pull into a helper method.

Comment: I have copied the bundle resources corresponding to Localizable.strings, but I always get the English version of the key, no matter which language the device has. Any idea @Manuel ?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution:

1. In your UI Tests target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, add the needed localization files (e.g. Localizable.strings).
2. Add a function similar to the following:

   ```
   func localizedString(key:String) -> String {
       /*1*/ let localizationBundle = NSBundle(path: NSBundle(forClass: /*2 UITestsClass*/.self).pathForResource(deviceLanguage, ofType: "lproj")!) 
       /*3*/ let result = NSLocalizedString(key, bundle:localizationBundle!, comment: "") // 
       return result
   }


   /*1 Gets correct bundle for the localization file, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086266/cant-get-access-to-string-localizations-in-ui-test-xcode-7 */
   /*2 Replace this with a class from your UI Tests*/ 
   /*3 Gets the localized string from the bundle */
   ```
3. Use the function like this: `app.buttons[localizedString("localized.string.key")]`

Comment: Is it not possible to get the deviceLanguage dynamically? I don't like the idea of having to specify the language of the device.. Does the UITest-class not have any sense of connection to the device it is testing on to get the localization from it?

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach written here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75178860/7715250. Copy paste for when the question is deleted/closed:

> ### Different approach without calling methods on your `String`
>
> **Prerequisites**
>
> You are using `NSLocalizedString`.
>
> **Step 1**
>
> Make sure you add the translations to your test targets (Go to your
> `Localizable` file and on the right side you can tap your UI test
> targets).
>
> **Step 2**
>
> Add this somewhere in your main target
>
> ```
> #if DEBUG
>     // Can be changed by UI tests to get access to localized content
>     var bundleForLocalizedTexts = Bundle.main
> #else
>     let bundleForLocalizedTexts = Bundle.main
> #endif
> ```
>
> **Step 3**
>
> Add this value to the parameter `bundle` in **all your**
> `NSLocalizedString`s, like this:
>
> ```
> NSLocalizedString(
>     "localized",
>     bundle: bundleForLocalizedTexts,
>     comment: ""
> )
> ```
>
> **Step 4**
>
> Override the method setUp in your `XCTestCase` subclass and add this
> line:
>
> `bundleForLocalizedTexts = Bundle(for: MySubclass.self)`
>
> **Step 5**
>
> Everything should work! All languages should work, no extra methods to call.