# Xcode 7 UITests with localized UI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

In my App I'm using `NSLocalizedString` to localize my app. Now I want to switch to `UITests` and have Testcode like this:

```
[tabBarsQuery.buttons["particiants"] tap];
```

This works for English but fails for other languages.

```
[tabBarsQuery.buttons[NSLocalizedString("PARTICIPANTS",comment:nil)] tap];
```

Fails - probably because Localizable.strings is in another bundle. How can I test a localized app?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I wanted to actually test the content of UI features and not just their existence, so setting a default language or using the accessibility identifiers wouldn't suit.

This builds on [Volodymyr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38133902/555807)'s and [matsoftware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40322076/555807)'s answers. However their answers rely on `deviceLanguage` which needs to be explicitly set in `SnapshotHelper`. This solution dynamically gets the actual supported language the device is using.

1. Add the `Localizable.strings` files to your UITest target.
2. Add the following code to your UITest target:

   ```
   var currentLanguage: (langCode: String, localeCode: String)? {
       let currentLocale = Locale(identifier: Locale.preferredLanguages.first!)
       guard let langCode = currentLocale.languageCode else {
           return nil
       }
       var localeCode = langCode
       if let scriptCode = currentLocale.scriptCode {
           localeCode = "\(langCode)-\(scriptCode)"
       } else if let regionCode = currentLocale.regionCode {
           localeCode = "\(langCode)-\(regionCode)"
       }
       return (langCode, localeCode)
   }

   func localizedString(_ key: String) -> String {
       let testBundle = Bundle(for: /* a class in your test bundle */.self)
       if let currentLanguage = currentLanguage,
           let testBundlePath = testBundle.path(forResource: currentLanguage.localeCode, ofType: "lproj") ?? testBundle.path(forResource: currentLanguage.langCode, ofType: "lproj"),
           let localizedBundle = Bundle(path: testBundlePath)
       {
           return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: localizedBundle, comment: "")
       }
       return "?"
   }
   ```
3. Access the method by `localizedString(key)`

For those languages with a script code, the `localeCode` will be `langCode-scriptCode` (for example, `zh-Hans`). Otherwise the `localeCode` will be `langCode-regionCode` (for example, `pt-BR`). The `testBundle` first tries to resolve the lproj by `localeCode`, then falls back to just `langCode`.

If it still can't get the bundle, it returns "?" for the string, so it will fail any UI tests that look for specific strings.

Comment: This works great for my `localizable.strings`! However, I cannot seem to get it to work with my Storyboard string files. Do you have any idea how I can fix that? Doesn't the storyboard strings go to the eventual lproj folder when building?

Answer (score 26):

### Option 1: Set a Default Language

Create a new scheme for UI Testing and set the default Application Language. This will lock the app into one localized file so you can write all of your tests for that language.

Set the option from Product -> Scheme -> Manage Schemes or <kbd>⌘⇧,</kbd>. Then select the Options tab and set the language.

[image: Xcode - Set the Default Application Language]

**Pros**: Simple, one-time change.

**Cons**: Cannot be used to create localized screenshots with [snapshot](https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot) (a tool that runs your app via UI Testing and generates App Store screenshots along the way).

### Option 2: Use `-accessibilityIdentifier` for Localized Strings

Instead of accessing items via their displayed text or value, use `accessibilityIdentifier`. This is read by the UI Testing framework but never shown or read to users (even with accessibility turned on). In the old UIAutomation docs Apple mentions using this for developer functionality, which this seams like a good use case.

You can then continue to set `accessibilityLabel` and `accessibilityValue` like normal, with the localized versions.

**Pros**: Can be used for more generic solutions, such as taking automated screenshots.

**Cons**: Might require more work changing each label you need "unlocalized" for testing.

Comment: I don't want to lock my app to one language because I would like to create localized screenshots with https://github.com/fastlane/snapshot

Comment: Please see my edit for a second option to use `accessibilityIdentifier`.

Comment: Thanks this is the answer i've been searching for! works great! multi language UITesting and taking screenshots with fastlane

Comment: @JoeMasilotti I'm using KIF so i'm not using XCUI and therefore i can't use snapshot but i'm trying to find a way to set multiple languages because i want to start my simulator in each one of this languages to force my app run in each language - test in each language. Do you have any idea about a workaround? Thanks.

Comment: How to address UIAlertsAction and UIAlertControllers as they dont respond to accessibility Ids. I tried with Accessibility Labels, they work fine in English but with other languages, its not working.

Comment: This gets a real problem when working with system buttons such as UIBarButtonItem - You cannot set it's accessibilityIdentifier =[ APPLE - DO SOMETHING

Answer (score 17):

**YOU CAN RE-USE YOUR PROJECT LOCALIZATION BUNDLES!**

When you test message boxes behaviour you need to know exactly what message box just appeared. You need to copy your localization from another scheme during build phase.

In your UI Tests target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources, add the localization files needed (e.g. Localizable.strings).

Add a function similar to the following:

```
func localizedString(key:String) -> String {
/*1*/ let localizationBundle = NSBundle(path: NSBundle(forClass: /*2 UITestsClass*/.self).pathForResource(deviceLanguage, ofType: "lproj")!) 
/*3*/ let result = NSLocalizedString(key, bundle:localizationBundle!, comment: "") // 
    return result
}

/*1 Gets correct bundle for the localization file, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086266/cant-get-access-to-string-localizations-in-ui-test-xcode-7 */
/*2 Replace this with a class from your UI Tests 
/*3 Gets the localized string from the bundle */
```

Then in your code you can use app.buttons[localizedString("localized.string.key")]

Full article is here: https://github.com/fastlane-old/snapshot/issues/321#issuecomment-159660882

Comment: tried this solution, but not worked because **deviceLanguage** is `en-US`, but resource is `en`. Changed to `Locale(identifier: deviceLanguage).languageCode`

Answer (score 6):

The simplest and reliable way for me so far is to reference elements with elementBoundByIndex()
Like this:

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let tabBar = app.tabBars
    tabBar.buttons.elementBoundByIndex(2).tap()
    app.navigationBars.buttons.elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
    app.tables.cells.elementBoundByIndex(2).tap()
    app.tables.elementBoundByIndex(1).cells.elementBoundByIndex(0).tap()
```

You can guess/experiment with this values and find elements you need.

Comment: rearrange layout later for whatever reason and you're screwed. tests will fail and go figure all the affected indexes each time. sorry but no, this is not even close to how reliable `accessibilityIdentifier` is. in order to make this feasible you should at the very least assign those elements to meaningful variable names

Comment: @keeshux I agree :) That's why accepted answer recommends using accessibilityIdentifier. I needed this tests for fastlane/snapshot. And you make new screenshots when your "layout changes". And it is by far the fastest way for me.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of Volodymyr helped me a lot, but it can fail if the localization bundle folder name differs from the deviceLanguage set in Snapshot. This snippet works fine for me in Swift 3.0 and with languages like italian (where current locale is "it" but device language is "it-IT").

```
    func localizedString(key:String) -> String {
      let languageBundlePath = Bundle(for: PlinthUITests.self).path(forResource: deviceLanguage, ofType: "lproj") ?? Bundle(for: PlinthUITests.self).path(forResource: NSLocale.current.languageCode!, ofType: "lproj")
      let localizationBundle = Bundle(path: languageBundlePath!)
      let result = NSLocalizedString(key, bundle:localizationBundle!, comment: "")
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. It's worth to mention that the variable _deviceLanguage_ is static and defined in **SnapshotHelper##setupSnapshot(_)**.

Comment: Unfortunately NSLocale.current.languageCode in my case was "en" while deviceLanguage was "de-DE". But in a comment to Volodymyrs answer Kirow gave the missing hint: Locale(identifier: deviceLanguage).languageCode

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joe's answer you can also force language for UI tests directly in test code without editing a scheme like this:

```
- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    self.continueAfterFailure = NO;
    XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
    app.launchArguments = @[@"-AppleLanguages", @"(en)", @"-AppleLocale", @"en_EN"];
    [app launch];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Different approach without calling methods on your `String`

**Prerequisites**

You are using `NSLocalizedString`.

**Step 1**

Make sure you add the translations to your test targets (Go to your `Localizable` file and on the right side you can tap your UI test targets).

**Step 2**

Add this somewhere in your main target

```
#if DEBUG
    // Can be changed by UI tests to get access to localized content
    var bundleForLocalizedTexts = Bundle.main
#else
    let bundleForLocalizedTexts = Bundle.main
#endif
```

**Step 3**

Add this value to the parameter `bundle` in **all your** `NSLocalizedString`s, like this:

```
NSLocalizedString(
    "localized",
    bundle: bundleForLocalizedTexts,
    comment: ""
)
```

**Step 4**

Override the method setUp in your `XCTestCase` subclass and add this line:

`bundleForLocalizedTexts = Bundle(for: MySubclass.self)`

**Step 5**

Everything should work! All languages should work, no extra methods to call.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this for the purpose of running Snapshot (rather than actual UI testing), then I find the simplest solution is to cheat and use [HSTestingBackchannel](https://github.com/ConfusedVorlon/HSTestingBackchannel)

It is a tool that I wrote which allows you to send notifications from the UITesting class to the app. You then write code in the app which responds directly to the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of SeanR is great (+1), but there is a minor improvement:

If you use base localization, then your `Localizable.strings` might not be localized in your base language. This is not necessary because the base language would be used in this case. If so, SeanR’s function `localizedString` would return `„?“`.

The extended version below checks additionally for the base language, and returns the localized string in the base language:

```
func localizedString(_ key: String) -> String {
    let testBundle = Bundle(for: ShopEasyUITests.self)
    guard let currentLanguage = currentLanguage else { return "?" }
    if let testBundlePath = testBundle.path(forResource: currentLanguage.localeCode, ofType: "lproj"),
        let localizedBundle = Bundle(path: testBundlePath) {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: localizedBundle, comment: "")
    }
    if let testBundlePath = testBundle.path(forResource: currentLanguage.langCode, ofType: "lproj"),
        let localizedBundle = Bundle(path: testBundlePath) {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: localizedBundle, comment: "")
    }
    if let testBundlePath = testBundle.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj"),
        let localizedBundle = Bundle(path: testBundlePath) {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: localizedBundle, comment: "")
    }
    return "?"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For fastlane's snapshot feature, the `SnapshotHelper.swift` launches app with these arguments. So by interpreting these values, this solution is deterministic, and I was able to produce correct snapshots for multiple languages:

```
func getLocale(str: String) -> String {
    let start = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
    let end = str.index(start, offsetBy: 2)
    let range = start..<end

    var locale = str.substring(with: range)
    if locale == "en" {
        return "Base"
    }
    return locale
}

func localizedString(_ key: String) -> String {
    print("app.launchArguments \(app.launchArguments)")
    guard let localeArgIdx = app.launchArguments.index(of: "-AppleLocale") else {
        return ""
    }
    if localeArgIdx >= app.launchArguments.count {
        return ""
    }
    let str = app.launchArguments[localeArgIdx + 1]
    let locale = getLocale(str: str)
    let testBundle = Bundle(for: Snapshot.self)
    if let testBundlePath = testBundle.path(forResource: locale, ofType: "lproj") ?? testBundle.path(forResource: locale, ofType: "lproj"),
        let localizedBundle = Bundle(path: testBundlePath)
    {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: localizedBundle, comment: "")
    }
    return ""
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C Solution : 
inspired by @Volodymyr Prysiazhniuk solution

```
- (NSString*)getLocalizedStringForKey :(NSString*)stringKey forUITestClass : (id) uiTestClass{
    if (!stringKey || !uiTestClass){
        return nil;
    }
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle bundleForClass: uiTestClass]bundlePath];
    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
    NSString* localizedString = NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(stringKey, nil, bundle, nil, nil);
    return localizedString;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I've made localized screenshots with Fastlane using next scheme:

1) Add to Fastfile next param:

localize_simulator: true

2) Use this code to get localized string:

```
class LocalizationHelper: NSObject {

    class func localizedString(_ key: String) -> String {
        let testBundle = Bundle(for: UITests.self)
        let currentLocale = Locale.current
        if let code = currentLocale.languageCode,
            let testBundlePath = testBundle.path(forResource: code, ofType: "lproj") ?? testBundle.path(forResource: code, ofType: "lproj"), let localizedBundle = Bundle(path: testBundlePath) {
            return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: localizedBundle, comment: "")
        }
        return ""
    }

}
```

Comment: If someone knows why this is not helpful, please let me know in comment. Would be happy to check it again and correct.